# PyQGIS problem to find the path of the Python script

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, import, qgis-python-console

I have two Python scripts. The main script import the second script

**test_credenziali.py** (main script)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=utf-8
# Copyleft Roberto Marzocchi - Gter srl Innovazione in Geomatica Gnss e Gis
import os,sys,shutil,re,glob, getopt
dirname0 =os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]) 

#dirname = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) #NameError: name '__file__' is not defined

dirname2= os.getcwd()
print('The path of the python script is ', dirname0 ) 
#print('The path of the python script is ', dirname ) 
print('The path of the python script is ', dirname2 ) 

# here i like to use the dirname variable
sys.path.insert(0, r'C:\Users\assis\Desktop\script_test')
from credenziali import *
print(host)
```

**credenziali.py**

```
host='domain.it'
```

I save both script in the same folder (e.g on my desktop) `C:\Users\assis\Desktop\script_test`

and if I use the following line before the import of *credenziali.py* it works

`sys.path.insert(0, r'C:\Users\assis\Desktop\script_test')`

Nevertheless I like to use relative path in order to call the *credenziali.py* script. Using python normally it works or I can use the command

`dirname = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))`

to obtain the path of the main script.

Using the QGIS Python console it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

What I believe is, (I may be wrong) that this happens because when you run a plugin the scripts are compiled and the files created, with extension .pyc are saved in the py_cache folder of your plugin.

But is Python supposed to be an interpreted language? Yes, but when you import a module, in this case os, that module is compiled in the .pyc file.

In the console I suppose that file is not accessible, or is temporary.

Let's hope a guru gives us better information.

Comment: Probably you are right. The strange thing is that using different console (e.g. the visualcode console for python) I can obtain the dirname without .pyc file